# How to scroll wigets that are in unequal size?

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

How can I make unequal widgets(MDCard for example) scrollable in kivy?
[image: This design for example]

How can I scroll unequal MDCards in two rows and multiple unequal columns(as shown in the above example)?

I've tried to scroll a stacklayout with ScrollView.

```
ScrollView:
    StackLayout:
        [All the unequall cards ]
```

But this didn't work.

I've tried to so something like..

```
ScrollView:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        BoxLayout:
            [Unequal cards]
        BoxLayout:
            [Unequal cards]
```

But this also didn't work.
How can I make this kind of scrollable design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `StackLayout` or in all three of the `BoxLayouts`, try adding:

```
size_hint_y: None
height: self.minimum_height
```

You need to use `minimum_height` (or something equivalent) in the child of a `ScrollView`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been trying to make the design from many days. Your solution solved my problem. Thanks again.